# Manipulate website dropdown menu in Python

Tags: python, html

I've been searching the web for an answer to the following question, and my lack of success might have to do with my inexperience in web programming/html. If so and there's an obvious answer, sorry for bugging you all.  I've been trying to parse a bunch of text from a website, and I found the python script html2text.py, which does a nice job of presenting the website in a way that I can parse.  However, in order to get to all the information, I need to access a drop down menu on the site.  The drop down menu controls which year of data is displayed, and I want to get all available years.  I've seen that with urllib2 I can access a website, and it looks like I can send information to a website that way too, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to manipulate the drop down menus.  The website I'm interested in is http://www.nfldata.com/nfl-stats/team-stats.aspx if that helps at all.  Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

-Matt

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I learned a lot more about xml/html. I found the select widget that affects which year is displayed, but I still can't quite figure out how to automatically request the website to change that option in python. The statistics I want are dynamically generated when these options are changed.  It looks like if I save each webpage (i.e., year) individually I can then extract the information I want from those html files.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the xml libraries within python. You can take the raw html text and parse it into a Document Object Model (DOM) interface:

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is not a Drop Down menu, but a Select widget.

You should be able to parse this, and find all of the `<option value="X">name<option>` entries. The X is what you need.